# I'm getting a package and I'm trying to find out what this phrase mean

Tags: translation

到达北京市国际邮件交换站Yanwen
北京市 in English ,north american thankyou

Answer (score 1):

到达北京市国际邮件交换站: Arrive at Beijing international mail processing center.